# Truffle test: getting Transaction Object instead of uint result

Tags: solidity, truffle, testing

I have a method in my contract like so:

```js
  mapping(address => uint256) allowance;

  ...

  function setAllowance(address user, uint256 amount) external onlyOwner nonReentrant returns (uint256) {
    allowance[user] = amount;
    emit AllowanceLimitChange(user, amount, ChangeType.None, allowance[user]);
    return allowance[user];
  }
```

In my truffle test, I am expecting it to return me a `uint256`, but it actually returns me a transaction object! Below is my test code:

```js
  it("should set allowance limits to non-zero", async () => {
    try {
      const value = web3.utils.toWei("0.2");
      const newAllowance = await contract.setAllowance(accounts[1], value);
      assert.equal(value, newAllowance); // assertionError
    } catch (err) {
      assert(false); // always come here because of assertionError due to type mismatch
    }
  });
```

Screenshot of Transaction Object received:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

**TLDR;**

Similar to this issue [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/67138/22522) , use `.call` after the function name. Then it works out!

```js
      const newLimit = await contract.setAllowance.call(kid1, value); // the .call() is the fix
```

**Edit**: (adding more details in the line of @GoodVibration's comments)

---

`setAllowance` is a non-constant call, which means it modifies contract state in some way. `constant` was used in older solidity code, which in modern versions are indicated via `view` (only reads state) or `pure` (no read from, or write to contract state).

When we invoke such a non-constant method, we will only get the transaction response as the return value, irrespective of what return value we might have coded in (in this case, `uint256`). Thus, we have two options:

1. use `.call` : this sort of "evaluates" the code inside the method, but not cause a transaction to happen, and thus no state change will be persisted. A test case to help explain things better:

```js
  it("will set allowance limits to non-zero within the scope of the method", async () => {
    try {
      const value = web3.utils.toWei("0.2");
      // https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/90342/22522
      const newLimit = await contract.setAllowance.call(accounts[1], value);
      assert.equal(value, newLimit); // we get a return value
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("error:\n", err);
      assert(false);
    }
  });

  it("proves that above call does not persist state change", async () => {
    const allowance = await contract.getAllowance(kid1);
    assert.equal(allowance, 0); // allowance did not change at all!!
  });
```

2. Invoke the method, **[and use Events for testing](https://github.com/rkalis/truffle-assertions)**: when we write `await contract.method(... args)` , that `method` is actually invoked, transaction goes through mining, and events are fired. While this is great, it will **always** return a Tx object as response, and not the return type you coded. As such you need to assert on the events that gets fired. something like this:

```js
  // smart contract
  event AllowanceChange(address user, uint256 oldLimit, string delta, uint256 newLimit);
  
  ...

  function setAllowance(address user, uint256 amount) external onlyOwner nonReentrant returns (uint256) {
    allowance[user] = amount;
    emit AllowanceChange(user, amount, "set", allowance[user]);
    return allowance[user];
  }

      
  // Truffle JS Test
  const value = web3.utils.toWei("0.2");
  const result = await contract.setAllowance(accounts[1], value); 
    truffleAssert.eventEmitted(
    result,
    "AllowanceLimitChange",
    (ev) => ev.newLimit.toString() === value,
    "Allowance Change event should be triggered"
  );
```

Comment: This answer is generally wrong. Using `.call` is mandatory when you use web3.js directly, but not when you use it via Truffle. The function in context - `setAllowance` is a non-constant function (changes the state of the blockchain), hence the value returned to the offchain caller is the transaction receipt and not the actual return-value (which is returned only to onchain callers).

Comment: And while your suggestion to use `.call` will allow this offchain caller (the test script) to obtain the actual return-value, it will also prevent the actual transaction from being executed (i.e., the state of the contract will remain the same). The correct way here is to obtain the returned-value through the event logs within the returned receipt.

Comment: @goodvibration yes, I have updated my answer along these lines. anything more I should be adding ?

Comment: Looks really good now IMO.